# Download a file without installing any non-default packages like wget or curl

Tags: downloads

Is there any built-in tool (e.g., found on a vanilla `ubuntu` Docker container, or found in a minimal Ubuntu Server install) that can download a file over HTTP? In other words, without having to execute `apt update && apt install [curl|wget]`.

I thought `perl` might be able to with `File::Fetch` but it isn't built-in. (You could create a TCP connection manually, but that's getting involved.)

Comment: If it's for building on the Docker image, there's [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add). Otherwise, Python might be an option for Ubuntu server.

Comment: @muru `ADD` is a good point, I didn't know it could fetch files.